# How to set up authentication method as json based POST request Data in zap API client?

Tags: owasp, zap

I am writing a python client to test a webapp using zap client library. As there was no json based auth method supported in stable zap release I am now using live zap container.

in python client, I have tried following thing:

```
login_config_params = ''.join(("loginUrl=https://x.x.x.x/login/&loginRequestData=",
                           urllib.parse.quote_plus("{\"username\":\"xxxxx\",\"password\":\"xxxxx\"}")))


zap.authentication.set_authentication_method(context_id, "jsonBasedAuthentication", authmethodconfigparams=login_config_params, apikey=apikey)
```

when this executes I don't see any logs in container regarding successfull setup.

Please help me to check if this has been okay and ready to go ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working out if authentication is set up correctly can be tricky when just using the API.

I'd recommend using the ZAP UI for testing as that allows you to see whats going on more easily - you can still use the API to configure ZAP but you can also see the requests and responses which makes debugginf easier.

Answer (score 1):

Most REST/JSON type APIs use some kind of Authorization header, so you should see what your app uses, and mimic that. Then add those headers to each request. For example if you have a cookie and an Authorization header:

`zap.replacer.add_rule('Auth Header', True, 'REQ_HEADER', False, 'Authorization', 'Bearer ' + auth_token)
zap.replacer.add_rule('Cookie', True, 'REQ_HEADER', False, 'Cookie', 'SESSIONID=' + sessionid)`

These will be included in every subsequent scan request.

Comment: @where we can that zap.replacer.add_rule inside ZAP UI ?